# PHP while loop - result under correct table header

Tags: php, html

I have a while loop which populates an html table, I've populated the headings outside of the while loop and then each row is added, but I wanted to know if it was possible to 'place' data under specific headings.

So I have a column header for each month, but want to populate the SQL data under the correct header, which I should be able to do, as SQL knows which month it is.

Here is my code so far ...

```
<?php     
echo "<div class=\"table-responsive\">";
  echo "<table class=\"table table-bordered\">";
    echo "<thead>";
     echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>August</th>";
        echo "<th>September</th>";
        echo "<th>October</th>";
         echo "<th>November</th>";
         echo "<th>December</th>";
         echo "<th>January</th>";
         echo "<th>February</th>";
         echo "<th>March</th>";
         echo "<th>April</th>";
         echo "<th>May</th>";
         echo "<th>June</th>";
         echo "<th>July</th>";
    while($row = $getData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

    echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Value'] . "</td>"; 
  if($row['Value'] <> $row['Old Value'])
         echo "<td style='background-color: #C0392B;'> <font color=\"#EEEEEE\">".$row['Value']."</font> </td>"; 
  echo "</tr>"; 

 }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
        ?>
```

As I said, I can fix this slightly by saying something like, `if Month = 'August'` in PHP, but I'm not sure how to place it under a specific heading of the table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you are drawing a table, with 12 elements of head , and only 2 elements of body;

Comment: you need to add more `<td>` to your table body

Comment: Yes Hassan, you are right, I just need to create blank tags then use a PHP if statement to populate them if there is a value there.